# simple_list_item_2 or two item listview with Firebase

Tags: java, android, listview

I would like to have two different text size items in a ListView using Firebase to pull the two items (eg. Name and specialist). 
This is currently being accomplished using a simple_list_item_2 but there's no way to set the bottom item size.

[Something like this, but a smaller font size for the specialist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFshi.png)

Comment: You can provide your own layout for the list item, but can you show us some code and xml to get an idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Create custom adapter class extending `BaseAdapter` with custom layout where you are going to setup `TextViews` according to your needs.